# Why This Code Not Executing After enter the value?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, sqrt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    printf("Enter The Number :");
    scanf(" %d \n" , &x);
    int xS= sqrt(x);
    printf("Square Root of The Given Number : %d" , xS);
}
```

after entering the value `120` , nothing is happening! I am using Clion. What do I have to Do?

Comment: The only think that belongs in that `scanf` format string is `"%d"`.

Comment: 1. remove the whitespace from the scanf string.  2. `sqrt` is returning a floating point number so it's not advisable to assign it into an `int`.

Comment: Problem is Solved by Removing /n. But Why was it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove whitespace and `'\n'` from the format string of `scanf`.

> An '\n' or any whitespace character in the format string of scanf
> consumes an entire sequence of whitespace characters in the input. So
> the scanf only returns when it encounters the next non-whitespace
> character, or the end of the input stream.

Answer (score 3):

From the standard (but with my emphasis):

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by ***reading input up to the first nonwhite-space character*** (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read.

That means your trailing white-space directive cannot be satisfied until it detects a non-space in the input stream, which it will leave there for the next input attempt. And you certainly don't need both the space *and* the newline, since the latter will simply look at the same character the former did and read nothing :-)

If you had entered `120`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, `x`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you would have seen it continue (with the `x` being left in the input stream).

In fact, you would be better off just using `"%d"` as the input specifier. This *already* ignores leading white-space before attempting to read the number (meaning the initail space is unnecessary), and you should not usually concern yourself with what *follows* the thing you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I couldn't tell you exactly why, but removing the \n from the scanf() seems to fix it.

Comment: It would be more better if you write this as ａ comment instead of an Answer.

Comment: It worked friend. Thank you Very Much, Do You Have any Idea Why was that?

Comment: @Epsilon Great! I'm not sure unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with this language but I messed about with it and got it working.

Comment: @Epsilon, If I had to guess it would be because you're trying to get input from the user and the compiler doesn't understand why you're using a newline statement since it won't print out anyway. I could be wrong though, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thnk you Very Much